# Converting Map type in Case Class to StructField Type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a case class which I want to convert to schema in Spark

```
case class test(request1:Map[String, Any],response1:Option[String] = None,)
```

How do I convert this class to schema object

```
val mySchema = StructType(
StructField("request1", Map[String, Any], false),StructField(" response1", Option[String],true))
```

Map and Options are not available in DataType

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to use this case class to create a `DataFrame` schema. While Spark supports map via [`MapType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.MapType) and `Options` are  handled using wrapped type with `Nones` converted to `NULLs`, schema of type `Any` is not supported.

Assuming you change `Value` type to `String`:

```
case class Test(request1: Map[String, String], response1: Option[String] = None)
```

corresponding schema should look like this:

```
StructType(Seq(
   StructField("request1", MapType(StringType, StringType, true), true),
   StructField("response1", StringType, true)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @zero323 already eloquently said, even though you can use `MapType`, it is probably not the best thing in your case. Your request and response are probably already structured and you should invest a bit of time to define that structure/schema. For example, you can define all the string type columns at once programmatically, all int type columns programmatically as in the code below.

In sql, `Option` translates to the third argument of `StructField` which is nullable and it is true or false - most times you will set it to true, so that null values are allowed.

You can define nested structures like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

case class Request(url:String, enc:String)
case class Response(code:Int, body:String)
case class Record( request:Request, response:Response)

val names = Array("url", "enc")
val requestStructType = StructType( names.map( name => StructField(name, StringType, true)))

/// example of StructType with differing types, programmaticaly, add more field names if needed
val respNamesInt = Array("code")
val respNamesString = Array("body")
val responseStructType =
      StructType( respNamesInt.map( name => StructField(name, IntegerType, true)) ++
                  respNamesString.map( name => StructField(name, StringType, true)))

// example of nested structures
val recordStructType =
      StructType( Array(StructField("request", requestStructType, false), // nullable = false
                        StructField("response", responseStructType, true))) // nullable = true
```

Comment: thanks KrisP. But I don't have access to changing structure.